# Respetar el formato al imprimir una factura pre-diseñada a una matricial LX-300 con C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo problemas con la impresión, he usado desde el componente [PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) y CrystalReport y siempre tengo el mismo error que no me respeta las posiciones que le mando a imprimir pues siempre el texto impreso se va a la izquierda.

Comment: el problema de toda la vidaaaa, en primer lugar sería bueno saber desde donde envías la información, si se trata de un entorno web, de escritorio, etc, la pregunta es demasiado amplia debería ser un error específico, deberías colocar el código que usas para imprimir, etc etc, creo que amerita un flag tu post si no lo editas con la información que te indico :/.

Comment: El título no corresponde con la pregunta, ¿podrías mejorlo?

Comment: Por favor se mas especifico en tu pregunta y agrega detalles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno después de tantas luchas lo hice con crystal report, no ha salido de la manera que esperaba pero funciona.

Primero traté de hacer una plantilla con las respectivas posiciones, pero al igual que siempre todo lo enviaba alineado a la izquierda.

Hasta que me di cuenta de que en la misma línea si mandaba imprimir 2 caracteres me respetaba la posición. Así que al empezar de cada línea le mandé a imprimir un punto, no es lo más apropiado creo yo pero me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

he usado Crystal Report hace buen tiempo justo para una Epson LX 3000 o 300, no recuerdo bien. El punto es que es matricial y tenia que hacer plantillas para imprimir en facturas; para solucionar eso debes colocar columnas con poco tamaño para dar ese espaciado y ajustar las preferencias del papel -> medirlo con regla.
En aquel entonces era perder tiempo centrando adecuadamente la plantilla, en fin, buena suerte, éxitos y muchas bendiciones!

Comment: bienvenido a StackOverflow. Esto, más que una respuesta que solucione la (poco clara) pregunta, parece más bien un comentario. En StackOverflow, a diferencia de los tradicionales foros, buscamos publicar como respuestas solamente las que sean relevantes y busquen responder directamente la pregunta que se hace. Lo demás, (como esto que yo publico) son comentarios, que se pueden hacer tanto a la pregunta, como a la(s) respuestas.